# Listview with edit text - auto scroll when appear keyboard

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a edit text in every listview row, i want to auto scroll when keyboard appear

I have added  this code **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"** in my menifetch.xml but did not work

my getview java code

// Create List Adapter

```
class CreateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
String[] strItecode=null;
String[] strItem;
String[] strQuantity;
Context context;

int temp;
CreateAdapter(Context context, String[] strItemcode, String[] strItem,
        String[] strQauntity) {
    super(context, R.layout.create_list_item, R.id.txtItemcode, strItemcode);
    this.context = context;
    this.strItecode = strItemcode;
    this.strItem = strItem;
    this.strQuantity = strQauntity;
   // text= new String[strItem.length];
}
private int editingPosition = 0;
private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              text[editingPosition] = s.toString();
          }
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
      };

public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    temp=position;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.create_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.txtItecode = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtItemcode);
        holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        holder.editQuantity = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editcreateQuantity);
        holder.editQuantity.setTag(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.editQuantity.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
   if(text[temp].contentEquals("0"))
       holder.editQuantity.setText("");
   else
    holder.editQuantity.setText(text[temp]);

    holder.editQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {       
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if(hasFocus) editingPosition = position;
        }
    });

    holder.editQuantity.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

    // The rest is good, just make sure to remove the call to setting the EditText's text at the end
    holder.txtItecode.setText(strItecode[position]);
    holder.txtItem.setText(strItem[position]);
  //  holder.editQuantity.setText(text[temp]);

    return convertView;


}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtItecode;
    TextView txtItem;
    EditText editQuantity;
}
```

}

Please Help Me how i can set auto scroll when keyboard appear

Thanks IN Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In your Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
        scrollMyListViewToBottom();
    }  

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    myListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I hope it can help you

Comment: change the function `scrollMyListViewToBottom` specifying a particular position in your `listview` as that of the item that is being edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **Activity**

```
listview.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
```